# Reading excel rows and simultaneously processing it

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, excel, db2-luw

I have an Excel sheet and its humongous.. Around like 200000 rows that needs to be processed.
All I have to do is read it and process them with a query on a DB2 table.  I have written the program where its more than 8 hours to process 5000 rows.

Is there a way where I can simultaneously read the excel  and execute the query. I want them to be independent of the process. I cannot use Parallel.for as reading and creating so many instance of threads is no advantage. ANy pipes and queues are of no use. THis is a dom method using and it does not read a row, it reads a string.. if there is a null value on the row, it executes the row and throws an null exception. I am well with Background workers and TPL's. Any idea or code would be appreciated. No DLL can be used apart from OPENXML

Ideally I do not want to add to array,, I want it in 2 diff variables and process them when read..

1. Read a row( only 2 columns, ignore other cols
2. create a thread to execute the row and in Parallel, execute the read row.
3. Merge into one single table.
4. display results.. Sounds simple but there are challenges.

.

```
Try
    Using spreadsheetDocument As SpreadsheetDocument =     spreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, False)

        Dim workbookPart As WorkbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart
        Dim worksheetPart As WorksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First()
        Dim sheetData As SheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements(Of SheetData)().First()
        For Each r As Row In sheetData.Elements(Of Row)()
            For Each c As Cell In r.Elements(Of Cell)()
                Dim text As String
                Try
                    text = c.CellValue.Text.ToString
                    Debug.Print(text.ToString)
                    If text IsNot Nothing AndAlso Trim(text).Length > 0 Then
                        Arr.Add(text.ToString)
                    End If
                    text = Nothing
                    j += 1
                Catch
                End Try
            Next
            text = Nothing
        Next
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Exception caught: " + ex.Message)
    Debug.Print(ex.Message.ToString)
    End
End Try
myArr = CType(Arr.ToArray(GetType(String)), String())
```

This is the process which is dividing the data into 2 parameters

```
For i As Integer = 2 To myArr.Count - 1 Step 2
    If i And 1 Then
        i = i - 1
    Else
        dstr = DateTime.FromOADate(Double.Parse(myArr(i).ToString())).ToShortDateString()
        'Debug.Print(dstr.ToString & "----->" & i.ToString & "TCID--->" & myArr(i + 1).ToString)
        DQueue.Enqueue(DateTime.FromOADate(Double.Parse(myArr(i).ToString())).ToShortDateString())
        Tqueue.Enqueue((myArr(i + 1).ToString()))
        TCArr.Add((myArr(i + 1).ToString()))
        dc.Merge(ProcessQueryODBC(dstr, myArr(i + 1).ToString))

        If dc.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            dt.Merge(dc)
        Else
            nFound.Merge(CreateDT(dstr, myArr(i + 1).ToString()))
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening a DB connection through ODBC. Can you export your data to a CSV file and then let DB2 perform the [import](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F3-6-2-4-58)?

```
somestring = "import from "myfile.csv" of DEL ...."
DoCmd.RunSQL somestring
```